# Algebraic Proof: Sum of Squares of 3 consecutive odd numbers = 12n+11

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, quadratics

I was doing a maths mock exam just today, and I found one question of a type I would normally not find difficult - well difficult. I came here due to it being a GCSE level question that I assume most would find *ridiculously* easy....

The question being: 'Prove that the sum of the squares of any three consecutive odd numbers is always 11 more than a multiple of 12'

So, I write out - being a non-calculator test:

$$
(2n+1)^2+(2n+3)^2+(2n+5)^2
$$
I expand the brackets and **expect** something *nice*... I get 
$$
(2n+1)^2+(2n+3)^2+(2n+5)^2 = 12n^2+36n+35
$$
Now, I *think* I know that

> 11 more than a multiple of 12

Means:
$$
12n+11
$$
But
$$
12n^2+36n+35 \neq 12n+11
$$

I don't know if I'm missing something fundemental here, whether I'm not seeing it, I mean the output does look similar in that 35 is 1 less than 36 in '36n' and there's a 12 there, but they're just not equal? How do? Thanks.

Comment: Note:  $12n^2+36n+35= 12\times (n^2+3n+2)+11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (2k+1)^2+(2k+3)^2+(2k+5)^2 = 12k^2+36k+24+11 \\=12(k^2+3k+2)+11$$ $$=12n+11\tag{$n=k^2+3k+2$}$$

Answer (score 0):

note that $$12n^2+36n+35=12n^2+36n+36-1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$12n^2+36n+35$$
if you do $35-11$, you get $24$ which is a factor of $12$, allowing everything to be factorised. so $$12n^2+36n+35= 12n^2+36n+24+11
= 12(n^2+36n+2)+11$$
So the number would always have a remainder of $11$ afterwards, because we have already multiplied it by $12$ to make it a multiple of $12$.